# Only add unit on valid number

Tags: sass

I'm trying to do a mixin that have optional arguments. This is a simplified version:

```
@mixin marginCalculator($size, $size2:"") {

    margin: $size * 1px unquote($size2 * 1px);
}
```

I'm just passing in numbers as arguments. But i only want the first one to be mandatory. No problem if it only would output the number but i need to add a unit to it.

As can be seen in the snippet above i'm trying to multiplicate `1px` with `""` which ouputs an error message. As it should! But i was hoping for the empty quote to be returned. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

## Check the type of the value being passed in

```
@mixin marginCalculator($size, $size2: "") {
  margin: ($size * 1px) (if(type-of($size2) == number, $size2 * 1px, null));
}
```

## Loop over a list

This is a much better solution since it will allow you to gracefully handle 3-value margins as well.

```
@mixin marginCalculator($size...) {
  $xs: ();
  @each $s in $size {
    $xs: append($xs, $s * 1px);
  }
  margin: $xs;
}

.foo {
  @include marginCalculator(1);
  @include marginCalculator(1, 2);
  @include marginCalculator(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Alternately:

```
@mixin marginCalculator($sizes) {
  $xs: ();
  @each $s in $size {
    $xs: append($xs, $s * 1px);
  }
  margin: $xs;
}

.foo {
  @include marginCalculator(1);
  @include marginCalculator(1 2);
  @include marginCalculator(1 2 3);
}
```

Output:

```
.foo .foo {
  margin: 1px;
  margin: 1px 2px;
  margin: 1px 2px 3px;
}
```

Comment: Wow! I used the alternate loop. Much better than my approach. Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [`if()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#if-instance_method) function to check if it has no value:

```
@mixin marginCalculator($size, $size2:"") {

    margin: ($size * 1px) if($size2!="", $size2 * 1px, null);
}
```

Here, i check it against the default, an empty string, and return the calculation if it isn't that, and `null` if it is. If we return an empty string, it'll cause a CSS error.